# how to use c++ to upload file to ftp server in centos?

Tags: c++, linux, ftp

I know there are some question about this, but i found them based on windows.

So is there any good and simple method can upload in centos(linux)?

it would be great if nothing need to install(better no package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can try to use `libcurl`, there is an example from curl repos:

https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/docs/examples/ftpupload.c